# JSON doesn't show the names of the choices in the choices column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have json code set for the choice column which is also a button.
My code doesn't display the names of the choices! What do I do wrong:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "min-height": "24px",
    "min-width": "130px",
    "display": "inline-flex",
    "align-items": "center",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "white-space": "nowrap",
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
    "margin": "9px 0px 9px 0px",
    "border-radius": "14px",
    "border-width": "=if(@currentField == 0, '1px', '0')",
    "border-style": "solid"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "role": "button",
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "Niet verzonden"
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-borderColor-neutralTertiaryAlt sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray--hover",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "Aangevraagd"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMauve sp-css-backgroundColor-BgViolet--hover sp-css-color-MauveFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    "Goedgekeurd"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground30 sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground30--hover sp-css-color-CoralFont",
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground30 sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground30--hover sp-css-color-MintGreenFont"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "flex": "auto"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField.display"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow",
        "class": "=if(@currentField == 0, 'sp-css-color-themePrimary', '')"
      }
    }
  ],
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "openApprovalDialog"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you apply this JSON for choice column? Is it a single selection choice or multiple selection choice column? Try using `"txtContent": "@currentField"` instead of `"txtContent": "@currentField.display"`.

Comment: Also, if it is a choice column, you should not use conditions like: `=if(@currentField == 0, 'sp-css-color-themePrimary', '')`. Use this to check for blank values: `=if(@currentField == '', 'sp-css-color-themePrimary', '')`. Let me know if it works after making these changes I suggested.

Comment: Yes i have applied the JSON for the choice column. And it's a single selection.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using single selection choice column in SharePoint online list, try using:

```
"txtContent": "@currentField"
```

instead of

```
"txtContent": "@currentField.display"
```

Also, if it is a choice column, you should not use conditions like (comparing with 0):

```
=if(@currentField == 0, 'sp-css-color-themePrimary', '')
```

Use this to check for blank values:

```
=if(@currentField == '', 'sp-css-color-themePrimary', '')
```